# Symfony 6 prefill field in dynamic form type

Tags: php, forms, symfony, dynamic

I am making a dynamic form but I can not prefill a field according to the value of the previous field.  If the name equals `jean` i want to add a color field and I want to prefill the jean's favorite color by example...

```php
class TestEventType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'jean'   => 'jean',
                    'pierre' => 'pierre',
                    'marie'  => 'marie',
                ],
            ]);

        $builder->get('name')->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, [$this, 'addColor']);
    }

    public function addColor(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form       = $event->getForm();
        $data       = $event->getData();
        $parentForm = $form->getParent();

        if ($data === 'jean') {

            $builder = $parentForm->getConfig()
                                  ->getFormFactory()
                                  ->createNamedBuilder('color', TextType::class, null, [
                                      'auto_initialize' => false,
                                      'required'        => false,
                                //    'empty_data'      => wrong behavior
                                  ]);
            $parentForm->add($builder->getForm());
        }
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => TestObject::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

If I use empty_data, it puts the value in the field, OK. The problem is that if I want to submit a form with this empty field, it will take the value of empty_data, which is incorrect.

I try `data => 'red'` but it doesn't prefill the field. I try 'blue' in the third param of the createNamedBuilder method but nothing too.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `POST_SET_DATA` event to modify your form fields.
`PRE_SUBMIT` event is triggered after submitting the form.

I did not test the code (you may have to do some adjustments), but it should look like this:

```php
class TestEventType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'jean'   => 'jean',
                    'pierre' => 'pierre',
                    'marie'  => 'marie',
                ],
            ])
            ->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, 
                [$this, 'addColor']
            )
        ;
    }

    public function addColor(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        if ($data['name'] === 'jean') {
            $form->add('color', TextType::class);
            // Default color
            $data['color'] = 'green';
            $event->setData($data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just a nitpick, in modern php when you want to create a reference to a method, use `$this->addColor(...)` , not `[$this, 'addColor']` - way more idiomatic ^^

Comment: `[$this, 'addColor']` is a callback using the callable syntax from PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php
See also symfony doc: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#event-listeners

Comment: yeah, i'm just arguing that it's fugly and you should use the [First class callable syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.first_class_callable_syntax.php) instead, like ```->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, $this->addColor(...) )```

Comment: No, this isn't good. this behaviour is connected to the `POST_SET_DATA` event, which happens before the user submits his data.  
it's an "hxr form" so I need to intervene after the `$form->handleRequest($request)` so after the `x_set_data events` ...

Answer (score -1):

To add data on a field you can use the value attribute, as example

```
$builder->add('body', TextType::class, [
    'attr' => ['value' => 'red'],
]);
```